# Метод приводит к ошибке JS

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var countChild = document.getElementById('get-price');
alert('WORK') //работает
</script>
```

а если

```
<script>
var countChild = document.getElementById('get-price').children[1];
alert('WORK') //а тут уже не работает
</script>
```

При чем и .innerHTML тоже приводит к неработоспособности. 
На локально сохраненной странице все работает, а вот на сервере - нет. Этот код вставлен в страницу VamShop. Может кто то подскажет в чем может быть подвох?

Comment: а элемент с id get-price точно присутствует в документе в момент срабатывания скрипта? просто если скрипт расположен до body, то `document.getElementById('get-price')` вернёт null, и попытка вызвать свойства и методы приведёт к ошибке

Comment: а можно ссылку на вариант на сервере?

Comment: Действительно, getElementById возвращает null. Но как? див с этим id идет чуть ниже вставки <script></script> (кстати по нему можно найти этот кусок кода, он там один) http://zverushka.org.ua/final/eheim-jager-nagrevatel-dlja-akvariuma-s-reguljatorom.html

Comment: >Но как? див с этим id идет чуть ниже вставки <script></script>

улыбнуло

Comment: ну а в чем все таки проблема?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая в консоли ошибка выскакивает? Самый простой подвох может быть в том, что на данной странице нет существует элемента с id='get-price'.

Comment: выше дал ссылку